# WSO2 API Manager "Unexpected EOF in prolog" Exception

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-api-manager

I am new to `WSO2API Manager` and here's the issue:

- I tried to start the server few days ago and it started successfully
- But when I tried to start it this morning (without any modifications to server configuration), it throws out an exception as follows:

  ```
  WARN - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Proxy configuration cannot be built from : WorkflowCallbackService.xml - Continue in fail-safe mode org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
  ```
- Removing all files (including original and server generated files)under `repository/deployment/server` and paste new copies of the original five folders(`axis2modules` etc) would solve the problem.

Anyone knows how to fix this by in other ways? Apparently it's not a good choice to remove those files when facing this error.

Comment: First of all, it is not a good practice to replace the content of the "repository/deployment/server" folder. Secondly,  it is very difficult of diagnosing this issue without providing the full wso2carbon log file. Can you please provide it?